# Under the ocean, sea

Tags: prepositions

If "under the ocean" or "under the sea" means underwater, under the surface. Then what should we say to point to something under the "under the ocean, sea"?

I was thinking of:

- Under the ocean floor.
- Under the sea floor.

Also, is **undersea** or **underocean** possible based on that **underground** is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say several things:

- Under the ocean floor
- Under the sea floor (or seafloor)
- Beneath the bottom of the ocean

There are technical terms like "lithosphere", but that's probably not what you want. You could also refer to the Earth's crust directly.

"Undersea" is a word. I've never heard anyone say "underocean",

Comment: Also, beneath the ocean floor.

Comment: Yes, you can mix and match.